# ClickOnce-Prerequisite Download restarts if internet connection is dropped

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, clickonce, prerequisites

I have created Clickonce setup for deployment with 4 prerequisites.

On client machine, if internet connection drops while they are running setup.exe, the prerequisite download restarts. So for example they are on 4 of 4, download will start from 1 of 4.

How to resume the download for clickonce prerequisites.

I dont face this problem, if prerequisite are installed via VS Installer(.msi).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

ClickOnce downloads all of the prerequisites before it starts installing any of them. So unfortunately, there's nothing you can do but start over if it fails in the middle of downloading them.